# Search API custom query processor

Tags: 8, commerce, search

I would like to create a custom query processor to filter Commerce products, based on a user field and a product field.

Users have a boolean field "hide special products", and products have a boolean field "special". If a user can't see special products, all special products have to be hidden in the Search API view.
I have to add this condition in the Search API index, but I haven't found an example of a query processor. Could some show me an example of this custom processor?

Comment: After some investigation I have found  a way to do it. I would like to add this solution in order to help others how to do it.